# Getting textfield value and set it another screen

Tags: objective-c

That the user entered value to a textfield I want to display another screen in the textview. So, I want to access a textfield value I used in another screen.
I don't know how to do because I'm new in ios programming.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppDelegate,

```
Nsstring *textString;
```

In FirstViewController.h and SecondViewController.h

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

In FirstViewController.m and SecondViewController.m

in ViewDidLoad function,

```
appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

You can get textField text ,

```
appDelegate.textString = yourTextField.text;
```

and in SecondViewController,

```
NSString* textStr = appDelegate.textString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a NSString in the appDelegate for your project.

```
  eg. NSString* copyStr;

  //Now InYourFirstViewController.m
  appDelegate.copyStr = yourTextField.text; 

  //InSecondViewController.m
  NSString* fetchText = appDelegate.copyStr;
```